# How to find out if html element got fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

i need to know when a special html element containing images has been fully loaded.

The problem with this html element is that it gets replaced fully in the DOM on button click.
**What can i do?** (i do not want to assign a handler to each of the containing images btw.)

Comment: There is no way to do this. The only way to find out when an image has finished downloading is to add a `load` event listener. If you use `querySelectorAll`, with a good selector, and a loop, it won't be hard.

Comment: given the case i am able to find a selector which selects all those images it might be that some of those images will be loaded already making it different to decide if all images have been loaded. what about this?

Comment: I understand what you mean; that is a tricky issue. Inserting a script block immediately after the HTML for the images should work, though I am not sure if it is guaranteed to work. If you want to guarantee it working, then you should dynamically create the images with `document.createElement('img')`, then add the event listener, before setting the `src`.

Comment: it will work.. i mean the one with the script tag - see my answer for this ;)

Comment: @Delan: unfotunately the table is delievered from a perl script on buttonclick - i got no chance to use document.createElement('img') here

Answer (score 0):

pretty ugly, but working

```
var soManyImgsInHere = 0;
var fooAttachEvent = function(whereAreTheImages_Container){
  var where = whereAreTheImages_Container; //shorthand
  var length = where.length;
  soManyImgsInHere = length;
  var imgs = where.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
    imgs[i].onload = function(){
      soManyImgsInHere--;
      if(soManyImgsInHere == 0){
        alert('all imgs fully loaded'); // do whatever you want here :) all images are now fully loaded
      }
  }
};
```

let's assume your images are in a div with the id "fooImages"

then simply use this function right under this div like that:

```
<div id="fooImages">
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
  <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
<script>fooAttachEvent(document.getElementById('fooImages'));</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: when the handler assignment takes place after one of those images is already loaded the whole thing won't work. that is the reason why it is important ewhen to assign the handler

Comment: what's your point? i don't get it. Just place <script>fooAttachEvent(document.getElementById('fooImages'));</script> at the very end of your page's content.. e.g. right before the body tag closes :) the script is looking for all images in that specific container to be fully loaded.. it does not care if only one has loaded..